# No warning about existing answers when answer is undeleted while I'm deleting the question

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, confirmation

Althoug the site will confirm for a deletion of a question with answer, but maybe there is still some race conditions.

What happenned:

I deleted one of my own question. The question is deleted without confirmation (about existing answers), the page become red and blank, says the question is not viewable anymore. I thought this is strange, since I should be able to view my own just deleted question. So I refreshed the page, then the deleted question is shown (as expected), but with an answer.

So maybe the answer is committed just when I'm deleting the question, thats why there is no confirmation about existing answer. I could have not been aware of the answer if I didn't refresh the page.

What to do is to minimize the race by checking the up to date status, even check it again after the deletion then post a warning in the after deletion page.

Note: there is still a small chance that there is no problem at all and the confirmation is shown when I tried to delete the question and I unconsciously skip the confirmation. What is for sure is when I tried to delete the question there is no answer shown in the page (but not very sure whether there is "one more answer" bar!).

**Updated**

From the timeline I found that the answer is first deleted then undeleted, not answered again.

answer undeleted at 5:33:09

question deleted at 5:34:22

Comment: Please link to that deleted question and/or check the timeline yourself (clock icon under the voting buttons at the left).